# Local memory for each CUDA thread

Tags: multithreading, cuda

I have a simple program below. My question is that where is "temp" actually stored? is it in global or local memory? I need array temp for each idx so that every thread has individual array temp. In this case, it is working properly. But in my actual program, when I tried to fill temp[0] from test2 it made the program stopped. Suppose we have 1024 threads then it only run the kernel around 200 threads. So, I am wondering whether temp is shared or not. If yes, maybe there is a collision there. I also did not get any error messsage. Please someone explain about this.

```
__device__ void test2(int temp[], int idx) {
    temp[0] = idx;
    printf("%d ", temp[0]);
}

__global__ void test() {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    int *temp = (int *) malloc(100 * sizeof (int));

    test2(temp, idx);
}

int main() {
    test << <1, 1024 >> >();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: CUDA does not "error" like C, if there is an error you are resposible for checking for it and printing it to screen. Also, if the error is in a code you are not showing, we can not help you with it. This is a susbet of the XY problem, i.e. you are asking about what _you think_ its the issue, rather than the issue.

Comment: In an case, no `temp` is not shared, even if it were in global memory. Each block has a limited amount of registries, so if you surpass that, then automatically the compiler will use global memory to store `temp`, but it will also make sure there are no write/read conflicts by allocating the required amount of `temp` variables, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Actually that code can represent my actual code. Because as you said, I tried to check step by step by printing something in each line and the problem is in array temp. For all thread, I only filled index 0 similar to the above example. But the program stopped. I solved the problem by creating matrix. Suppose I have 1024 threads then I create 1024x100. each thread will have 100 elements. And it is working fine in my actual code. There are some mystery that i can't understand. @AnderBiguri

Comment: So, you said that the above code is fine. OK then, I will double check, because some methods use same structure and I got the same problem. @AnderBiguri

Comment: I didn't say its fine, I said that you are not checking for errors and yo shoudl. haven't looked at the code, just answered your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is that where is "temp" actually stored?

The allocation for `temp` is stored in a place called the device heap.  It is a form of global memory.  However the `temp` variable itself (i.e. the pointer value) is in local memory - not shared or visible to other threads.

> I need array temp for each idx so that every thread has individual array temp.

You will get that, subject to caveats below.  Each thread will have its own individual array, referenced by its local variable `temp`.  Each thread will have a separate allocation for storage on the device heap.

People commonly have problems with in-kernel `new` or `malloc`.  One of the main reasons is that the device heap is initially limited to 8MB, across *all* of your device heap allocations.  So if enough threads do a `new` or `malloc` of enough allocation requests, you will run out of space.

When you run out of space, the API way to signal that is to return a zero pointer value for the allocation (a NULL pointer).  If you then attempt to use this NULL pointer, you will have trouble.

For debugging purposes (i.e. to prove this is happening), test the pointer for NULL (i.e. `== 0`) before using it. If it is NULL, don't use it (perhaps print an error message instead).

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) or in many questions here on the SO `cuda` tag.  If you read any of these sources, you will discover that you can increase the size of the device heap.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @RobertCrovella. Another similar question: Suppose that array temp has 4k elements and I store it in global memory using  __device__, and I have 1024 threads, each thread will read all element in temp. so we have 4000*1024 iteration in total. Why in my kernel, the program stopped working. is it memory issue also or maybe accessing same index from different threads makes the problem?

Comment: Let's see, 4k elements is 4k `int` quantities.  That is 16 Kbytes.  Multiply that by 1024 threads and you have 16MBytes.  In my answer I mentioned a limit of 8MBytes

Comment: So, 8MBytes is for entire the device? So, what makes CUDA powerful? I am still have a problem with this. I created enough array but my recursive program keeps saying out of bound even I only use 1 thread. It stopped working after 132x calling one other method. ex: a call b 132x, in b I call element in array but it stopped after index 132. Do you have any idea? @RobertCrovella

Comment: 8MBytes is for the entire device.  Thats what "across all.." in my answer means.  But you can change the limit.  Perhaps you should read the documentation I linked in my answer.  I can't tell you what is happening in code you haven't shown.

Comment: I tried to change the limit. But nothing changed, "CUDA Error: an illegal memory access was encountered" still appears. The error comes when it is calling 8th level of recursion. Within this recursion, I tried to print all variable and the values are zero. Before this level, the variable values are correct. do you have any idea about what happen? or maybe you can share your email because I cant post the code here. @RobertCrovella